# How establish autologin on Lubuntu 22.04 after removing lxqt and openbox

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, init, auto-login

On Lubuntu 22.04 I ran

```
sudo apt purge autoremove ... *lxqt* *openbox* ...
```

and installed icewm to run my system with just that window manager. Everything works well, but in the process I lost automatic login.
Now, when X11 starts I am presented with a blue login screen asking for my user name and password. On providing these it transfers control to icewm-session which runs my startup apps.

Trying to discover how to re-establish autologin I ran

```
  cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/sddm
  systemctl status display-manager 
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-06-13 13:43:51 PDT; 16min ago
```

and /etc/sddm.conf contains

```
[Autologin]
User=q
Session=Lubuntu
```

But the autologin is no longer activated by sddm. How can I restore it, or establish it by some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be really easy. Just had to change /etc/sddm.conf from

```
[Autologin]
User=q
Session=Lubuntu
```

to

```
Session=Lubuntu
[Autologin]
User=q
```

Note: q is my username.